# Membership Provider, Allow same Username and Email

Tags: c#, web-applications, asp.net-membership

I know the title is confusing but let me elaborate a bit.

I have an application that allows you to create companies.
Each company has its own unique sub domain and when you go to that url you can registered for only that company and login for only that company.

What I want to achieve is to allow users of **company a** to have (possibly) the same username and/or email address for **company b**.

I have looked into this in the past and I think it has something to do with the application Id.
I already have a custom **ProfileRepository** which pulls in much more data that the **Membership.GetUser()** method so it doesn't matter to me if there is different application ids.

If I can create a user and specify the application id in the **Membership.CreateUser()** method that would be ideal, if not I need a work around.

Can anyone help?

Cheers,
r3plica

Comment: What's wrong with a PersonCompany mapping table with Id, PersonId and CompanyId. This was you have a many to many relatiosship between people and companies. You can check this when sharing login details across companies.

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue. I already have a profile table with exactly that

Comment: Sorry, then I don't understand your issue. If you have a view/page/area for your company then you have access to the company id, at the login send that to the server (in a hidden field or something) along with the username and password, get the profile id from the unique username, check that this person has the rights to log in to this company (mapping table) check password and email match, and allow/disallow them to log in. Apologies if I don't understand the particular issue.

Comment: The problem is when registering. Checking the user isn't an issue. But when I register a user, I want to be able to use the same username for each company

Answer (score 0):

In ASP membership applications have to be defined when you define the provider. 
Then you use

```
Membership.Providers["ProviderName"].CreateUser()
```

to create a user for that application.

Unfortunately I don't think that there is a way to create applications dynamically so they would all need to be defined in your web config with a different application name

Answer (score 0):

For the e-mail:

There is a section in web config to allow more users to have the same mail

```
<providers>
    <add name="xxx" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
```

For the user you could use a prexif (i.e. companyname/username).

Comment: yeah, I am aware of the email option :) The main issue is the username

Comment: I don't think you have other options other than using a composed username and hide it in the Login page